# Can’t get “eth1” working on a dual IP CentOS VPS setup

Tags: linux, networking, centos

Today I got a VPS with 2 IP addresses.

The IP on `eth0` is working when I do `ping -I eth0 www.google.com` I got 0% packet loss but when I do `ping -I eth1 www.goole.com` I got 100% packet loss.

This is the `ifconfig` output:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 185.8.49.12  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 185.8.49.255
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe84:5ed6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:50:56:84:5e:d6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 5716  bytes 398892 (389.5 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 933  bytes 294738 (287.8 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 185.8.49.157  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 185.8.49.255
    ether 00:50:56:84:5e:d7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 56  bytes 8896 (8.6 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 56  bytes 8896 (8.6 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

This is the output of `ifcfg-eth0`:

```
DEVICE=eth0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=185.8.49.12
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=185.8.49.1
DNS1=62.149.128.4
DNS2=62.149.132.4
```

And this is the output of `ifcfg-eth1`:

```
DEVICE=eth1
NM_CONTROLLED=no
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth1"
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=185.8.49.157
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=185.8.49.1
```

I have tried to reboot the system but nothing works.

Comment: its the same `eth0` works when pinging 8.8.8.8 and `eth1`does not i have added the same dns to `eth1`and it still gives me host unreachable

Answer (score 1):

"DEFROUTE=yes" on both interface configs doesn't do what you think it does.

Reboot (to clear any tinkering you've done) and run "ip route".
You should see something like :

```
# ip route
default via 185.8.49.1 dev eth0
185.8.49.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 185.8.49.12 
185.8.49.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 185.8.49.157
```

When you issue "ping -I eth1 8.8.8.8", because the system isn't configured with a default gateway reachable off eth1, ARP requests are sent out all interfaces to find 8.8.8.8 on the local network :

```
# ping -I eth1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 185.8.49.157 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 185.8.49.157 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 185.8.49.157 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 185.8.49.157 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 185.8.49.157 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

# tcpdump -ni eth0 'arp'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
05:07:42.821526 ARP, Request who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 185.8.49.157, length 46
05:07:43.821185 ARP, Request who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 185.8.49.157, length 46
05:07:44.823000 ARP, Request who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 185.8.49.157, length 46

# tcpdump -ni eth1 'arp'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
05:07:42.820834 ARP, Request who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 185.8.49.157, length 28
05:07:43.820864 ARP, Request who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 185.8.49.157, length 28
05:07:44.822841 ARP, Request who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 185.8.49.157, length 28
```

(Obviously Google's DNS server isn't on the same subnet as your VPS.)

Go ahead and try to add the second default route :

```
# ip route add default via 185.8.49.1 dev eth1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

Looks like the system won't readily accept multiple default routes.
And that makes some sense - how else would the device know through which of its multiple gateways to send a packet ? 
Would it send a copy per gateway ... then deal with multiple return packets ? Or would it send out packets arbitrarily, in a non-deterministic fashion (a nightmare to troubleshoot) ?
Presumably it could load balance, so let's try that :

```
#ip route delete default
#ip route add default scope global nexthop via 185.8.49.1 dev eth0 weight 1 nexthop via 185.8.49.1 dev eth1 weight 1
#ip ro
default 
        nexthop via 185.8.49.1  dev eth0 weight 1
        nexthop via 185.8.49.1  dev eth1 weight 1
...
```

But does it work ?

```
# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=17.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=18.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=17.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=15.3 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.337/17.227/18.762/1.241 ms

# tcpdump -ni eth0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
05:46:31.837933 IP 185.8.49.12 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 2382, seq 1, length 64
05:46:31.855566 IP 8.8.8.8 > 185.8.49.12: ICMP echo reply, id 2382, seq 1, length 64
05:46:33.842373 IP 185.8.49.12 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 2382, seq 3, length 64
05:46:33.859469 IP 8.8.8.8 > 185.8.49.12: ICMP echo reply, id 2382, seq 3, length 64

# tcpdump -ni eth1 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
05:46:32.840535 IP 185.8.49.157 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 2382, seq 2, length 64
05:46:32.859029 IP 8.8.8.8 > 185.8.49.157: ICMP echo reply, id 2382, seq 2, length 64
05:46:34.843725 IP 185.8.49.157 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 2382, seq 4, length 64
05:46:34.859020 IP 8.8.8.8 > 185.8.49.157: ICMP echo reply, id 2382, seq 4, length 64
```

**TA-DA !**
Now it's up to you to decide whether load-balancing is something you *really need* and are willing to support.